# What is a LAMP stack?

Tags: lamp

What does the term LAMP Stack mean?

I have seen this reference in job postings, but I don't fully understand the meaning of it.

I feel like in my development I use LAMP fairly commonly, but when I hear "stack" I feel like I am not using a LAMP environment as I should be.

---

I know what LAMP means and just wanted to know what the term "stack" tacked on meant.

Comment: [LAMP (software bundle)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29)

Comment: Just to put it out there, there's also WAMP - LAMP but for Windows. Windows Apache Mysql PHP.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

The reason they call it a stack is because each level derives off its base layer. Your operating system, Linux, is the base layer. Then Apache, your web daemon sits on top of your OS. Then your database stores all the information served by your web daemon, and PHP (or any P* scripting language) is used to drive and display all the data, and allow for user interaction.

Don't be overly concerned with the term 'stack'. People really just mean software suite or bundle, but you're using it just fine I am sure as you are.

Comment: Here is short guide to LAMP stack. helped me a lot.
https://medium.com/@codingmonk.tech/setting-up-lamp-on-digital-ocean-in-5-minutes-9b6984414c50

Answer (score 42):

**Linux** operating system

**Apache** web server

**MySQL** database

and **PHP**

Reference: *[LAMP (software bundle)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29)*

The *"stack"* term means *stack*! That means if you have experience in working with these technologies/framework or not. Since all these come together in a LAMP package, which you can download and install, they call it a stack.

Comment: Oh, well I know what LAMP means, I just didn't know what the term "stack" tacked on meant.

Comment: @Eli: It means it is just a stack!

Comment: ... and PHP Server-side scripting language :)

Answer (score 31):

That simply means using [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux), [Apache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server), [MySQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) and [PHP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) as your *[operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system)*, *[web server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server)*, *[database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system)*, and *[programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language)*, respectively.

Comment: thank you, I thought it might of meant the process of creating cron jobs or other processing scripts via a linux install

Answer (score 15):

LAMP means: L = [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) ([OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system)) A = [Apache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) ([web server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server)) M = [MySQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) ([database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system)) P = [PHP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) ([language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language))

From *[LAMP](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/L/LAMP.html)* (Wikipedia):

> Short for Linux, Apache, MySQL and PHP, an open-source Web development platform, also called a Web stack, that uses Linux as the operating system, Apache as the Web server, MySQL as the RDBMS and PHP as the object-oriented scripting language. Perl or Python is often substituted for PHP.

Answer (score 12):

For anyone still looking into this in order to learn specifically what a stack is, the term "stack" is referring to a "solution stack."  A solution stack is simply a complete set of software to address a given problem, usually by combining to provide the platform or infrastructure necessary.  This term is the parent of both "server stack" and "web stack."  Accordingly, a LAMP stack is a specific and complete set of software specifically aimed at serving dynamic content over the web.

Some extra reading:

https://www.techopedia.com/definition/28154/solution-stack
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_stack

Answer (score 7):

To be precise and crisp

LAMP is L(Linux) A(Apache) M(Mysql) P(PHP5) is a combined package intended for web-application development.

The easiest way to install Lamp is as follows

1) Using tasksel

Below are the list of commands

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tasksel
sudo tasksel ( will give you a prompt check the LAMP server and select Ok)

Thats it LAMP is ready to glow your knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

Lamp stack stands for **L**inux **A**pache **M**ysql **P**HP

there is also Mean Stack **M**ongoDB **E**xpressJS **A**ngularJS **N**odeJS

Comment: What "LAMP" means has already been explained in other answers.

Answer (score 3):

Linux, Apache, MySQL and PHP.  free and open-source software. For example, an equivalent installation on the Microsoft Windows family of operating systems is known as WAMP. and for mac as MAMP. and XAMPP for both of them

Answer (score 3):

L for Linux operating system
A for apache web server
M for Mysql database 
p for php for scripting and php modules

We can host php programs and cgi programs in LAMP system.

eg: In ubuntu apt-get install apache2 for web server
    apt-get install mysql-server php5-mysql for database and php
    apt-get install php5 
and got to your web server http://localhost

Answer (score 2):

I’ll try to answer the actual question of what a stack is.

In the Internet architecture ([TCP/IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite), [OSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model), etc.), protocols and software are often “stacked” on top of each other, as they depend on each other for support. For example, TCP provides reliable transmissions of data, on top of IP. The same goes for LAMP, your Apache server needs to run “on top of Linux”. Think of this “stack” as your favorite stack of pancakes, where each pancake is a different layer.

[image: LAMP pancake stack]

Yummy.

Answer (score 2):

There are various technological stacks present. Have a look:

LAMP:

**L**inux 
**A**pache 
**M**ySQL 
**P**HP

WAMP:

**W**indows 
**A**pache 
**M**ySQL 
**P**HP

MAMP:

**M**ac operating system 
**A**pache web server 
**M**ySQL as database 
**P**HP for scripting

XAMPP:

**X** is cross-platform 
**A**pache 
**M**ySQL 
**P**HP 
**P**erl

MEAN:

**M**ongoDB 
**E**xpress.js 
**A**ngular 
**N**ode.js

MERN:

**M**ongoDB 
**E**xpress.js 
**R**eact 
**N**ode.js